# I want to start a method or some process and hold for 100ms and start again in android

Tags: java, android

My Code is:

I want this process to hold for 100 ms and start again:

```
if ((X > 0 || X < 00) && (Y > 0 || Y < 0) && (Z > 0 || Z < 0)) {
    stepcounter++;
    stepC = Integer.toString(stepcounter);
    step.setText(stepC);
}
```

Comment: read about handler with post delayed

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You should just use:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(()->{ 
//Your Code
},100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a handler like so:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 0.1s = 100ms
    }
}, 100);
```